# UWP Slow back button on Local Machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am writing Windows 10 Universal App, and I need to add ordinary method

```
    private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;


        if (rootFrame == null)
            return;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }

        //debug
        int stop = 0;
    }
```

...in my

> App.xaml.cs

that will handle the Back button function of the device.

I am using it here:

```
       protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
            rootFrame.Navigated += OnNavigated;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

            // Register a handler for BackRequested events and set the
            // visibility of the Back button
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                rootFrame.CanGoBack ?
                AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
                AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

Its works fine, but the problem is when I build and run in on Local Machine and use Back Button to navigate between pages its took around 5000 - 6000 ms (5-6 seconds) to navigate to previous page.

When I debugged it, The delay between:

```
    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }

    //debug
    int stop = 0;
```

rootFrame.GoBack(); and debug variable "stop" is 5,778 ms...., when I run it on Mobile Emulator or Mobile Device the delay time is reduced to ~100ms

I will be grateful is someone is able to help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your demo? Did you register `BackRequested` in the code behind of each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what causing the delay, It was two SQL transactions methods in my MainPage file, which used to get to much data from SQLite Database file. They were called everytime when the paged is called. (Placed in page constructor). I move them in separate class and everythins seem to be fine.